# Call function after loop after fail to satisfy the condition

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, infinite-loop

Sorry it's a basic question. What is the best way to loop forever. I know a way how to do it by using while loop but i am not sure if that efficient way to do it.

I am trying to keep running the function looper. Inside the function there are multiple conditions. Based on a value one of the condition will trigger. At the end the function will start over and test the value again to see if will fit in one of the conditions again over and over.

I really appreciate it!

```
function looper(){
If (condition) do something 


   else // loop again 
    } 
looper();
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Currently, it's very unclear

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? An infinite loop is probably not going to be your ideal solution...

Comment: The best way to loop forever is by using any loop with an always true condition. `while(True){ }`, or any other loop. If you are trying to do it using a function, you will end up in a stack overflow or a similar out of memory situation due to infinite recursion.

Comment: I am trying to keep running the function looper. Inside the function there are multiple conditions. Based on a value one of the condition will trigger. At the end the function will start over and test the value again to see if will fit in one of the conditions again over and over.

Comment: @user14435220 In the browser or in a worker thread?

Comment: I want to run it on node js. I am prepare Linux server. I don't to crash the code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this variant would satisfy your condition:

```js
let j = true;
function loop(){
    if (j == true) return;
    else {
        console.log("u cant escape");
        loop();
    }
}
loop();
```

Comment: This will end up crashing with a Stackoverflow as each call to a function needs to store some info even if it’s just where to return to.

Comment: Yes, I know. But the author wants to create infinity loop. Of course, he can change the condition to condition what he needs. However, the idea of function with infinity loop without the condition of exit is weird.